# Variable X not updating when variables that should effect X change

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner at python. As most beginners, I am trying to make a text based rpg. I have finally gotten to the leveling up system and am at another roadblock. When the character levels up, they get to allot x skill points to a skill (add x to a variable x times). two of these variables effect the health of the character, however, when these two variables are changed by the user, the health variable stays the same. I have simplified my code for ease of reading (as my prose above is not that clear to begin with lol):

```
class Char:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.str = x
        self.con = y
        self.hp = (self.con + self.str) / 2


player = Char(20, 20)


def main(dude):
    print("strength:     " + str(dude.str))
    print("constitution: " + str(dude.con))
    print("hp: " + str(dude.hp))
    print("------")
    action = input("press 1 to change str, 2 to change con")
    if action == "1":
        dude.str = dude.str + 10
        main(dude)
    elif action == "2":
        dude.con = dude.con + 10
        main(dude)
    else:
        main(dude)


main(player)
```

although these variables can increase by increments of ten in this situation, the hp remains at 20

how can I remedy this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you attempt to modify `dude.hp`....Do you want the `hp` to automatically update when you modify `con` or `str`?

Comment: the relationships between variables aren't dynamic. If you say `x=5 y=5 z=x+y`, `z` is 10. it doesn't change if you set `x=6` after the fact

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes I want it to auto-update, sorry if that was not clear

Comment: @SuperStew How could I make them dynamic? again, I am pretty new to this. thanks for your help

Comment: @DominicDiTaranto you can't really make them dynamic, but you could write some kind of update function in the `Char` class. You may be able to have it "listen" for variable changes, but i don't think that will be straight forward

Comment: @SuperStew if you could just point me in the right direction, should I search for "listen"?

Comment: See: [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](//stackoverflow.com/a/49114700) and this example: https://ideone.com/zVjPQu

Comment: @DominicDiTaranto Johnny's link looks like a good start

Comment: @SuperStew I will look into it, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever the Char's attributes are updated, the code needs to re-compute the HP.
All this sort of code is best put inside the `Char` object:

```
class Char:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.str = x
        self.con = y
        self.setHP()

    def __str__(self):
        text = "strength:     " + str(self.str) + "\n" +\
               "constitution: " + str(self.con) + "\n" +\
               "hp:           " + str(self.hp)
        return text

    def setHP(self):
        self.hp = (self.con + self.str) / 2

    def adjustStr(self, amount):
        self.str += amount
        self.setHP()

    def adjustCon(self, amount):
        self.con += amount
        self.setHP()


def main(dude):
    print(str(dude))
    print("------")
    action = input("press 1 to change str, 2 to change con")
    if action == "1":
        dude.adjustStr(10)
        main(dude)
    elif action == "2":
        dude.adjustCon(10)
        main(dude)
    else:
        main(dude)


player = Char(20, 20)

main(player)
```

Comment: clever way to do it, and without the decorator headache

Comment: @Kingsley This method is great! thank you so much. Very easy to implement. And thank you for the idea of adding "def __str__(self):"

Answer (score 2):

The `hp` attribute does not change when the `str` or `con` change. The only time it is set is in the constructor. You could define an update method to `Char` like this:

```
class Char:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.str = x
        self.con = y
        self.update()
    def update(self):
        self.hp = (self.con + self.str) / 2
```

and call it at the end of `main`:

```
def main(dude):
    print("strength:     " + str(dude.str))
    print("constitution: " + str(dude.con))
    print("hp: " + str(dude.hp))
    print("------")
    action = input("press 1 to change str, 2 to change con")
    if action == "1":
        dude.str = dude.str + 10
        main(dude)
    elif action == "2":
        dude.con = dude.con + 10
        main(dude)
    else:
        main(dude)
    dude.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you evaluate the `hp` attribute only in the `__init__()` method, i. e. only in your statement

```
player = Char(20, 20)
```

The most quick fix (not a very nice one, but a very simple) is to *create a new instance of Char after each change:*

```
if action == "1":
    dude.str = dude.str + 10
    dude = Char(dude.str, dude.con)     # new dude (with current str and con)
    main(dude)
elif action == "2":
    dude.con = dude.con + 10
    dude = Char(dude.str, dude.con)     # new dude (with current str and con)
    main(dude)
```

Comment: @DominicDiTaranto, I added a hotfix into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the hp each time, since you used self.str and self.con only once to compute hp and stored it independently from self.str and self.con. You could use a get_hp for that.

```
class Char:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.str = x
        self.con = y

    def get_hp(self):
        return (self.con + self.str) / 2

player = Char(20, 20)


def main(dude):
    print("strength:     " + str(dude.str))
    print("constitution: " + str(dude.con))
    print("hp: " + str(dude.get_hp()))
    print("------")
    action = input("press 1 to change str, 2 to change con")
    if action == "1":
        dude.str = dude.str + 10
        main(dude)
    elif action == "2":
        dude.con = dude.con + 10
        main(dude)
    else:
        main(dude)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the other answers, as the best way for me would have been to use a property. Properties work just like getters, but has the benefit to allow it to be dynamically calculated, which is exactly what you are looking for.

```
class Char:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.str = x
        self.con = y

    @property
    def hp(self):
        # todo handle negative hp!
        return (self.con + self.str) / 2.


def test_hp():
    player = Char(20, 20)
    assert player.hp == 20


def test_hp_with_changes_to_con_or_str():
    player = Char(20, 20)
    player.con += 10
    assert player.hp == 25
    player.str += 10
    assert player.hp == 30
```

Also, as you can see, it is better to just write a test than to test stuff with output to stdout.

```
scratch_12.py ..                                                         [100%]

========================== 2 passed in 0.20 seconds ===========================
```

The above `hp` property is read-only, but you can make a setter for it as well if needed. Read up on [property](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

PS: also, use full names, like `Character` as it is better to be explicit than implicit :)