# Why do I need an explicit check in a while statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
contig = deque()
contig.append(2)
answer = 0
while contig:
    dist = contig.popleft()
    val = 0
    total = pow(2, val)
    while total < dist:
        val += 1
    if total == dist:
        answer += 1
        val = 0
    elif total > dist:
        answer += 1
        contig.append(dist - pow(2, val - 1))
        val = 0

print(answer)

================================code below this line contains no infinite loop
contig = deque()
contig.append(2)
answer = 0
while contig:
    dist = contig.popleft()
    val = 0
    while pow(2, val) < dist:
        val += 1
    if pow(2, val) == dist:
        answer += 1
        val = 0
    elif pow(2, val) > dist:
        answer += 1
        contig.append(dist - pow(2, val - 1))
        val = 0
print(answer)
```

All this can be simplified into :

```
zz = 1
jj = 0
while zz * jj < 10 :
    jj += 1
    print(zz, jj  )
###############################below this line contains an infinite loop
while True:
    z = 1
    j = 0
    r = z + j
    while r < 10:
        j += 1
        print(z, j , r )
```

Can anyone provide an explanation on why it works this way? It was marked as duplicate and closed by someone, but I was chatting with a user about it and their explanation was as follows :
[image]

No disrespect, but I am not really understanding what is going on for my exmaple. They linked [Variable X not updating when variables that should effect X change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843061/variable-x-not-updating-when-variables-that-should-effect-x-change) this post, but I am also not seeing the relationship here. At any rate, could someone provide an explanation in regards to the examples that I am giving? According to user it doesn't have anything to do pass by reference or value, Thanks a lot all.
Also, the user says that total = pow(2,val) sets the value of total once and never updates it again, but why should it not update? the program does check if total < dist, thats in the while loop. As far as I can see, the issue is that it always refers to the first time I declared it. Why is this case? I also tested this in c++ and am getting the same results.

Edit* right total is not modified, but total is defined to be comprised of 2 values outside of the loop, and those values are updated, so why doesn't this update reflect in the while condition check? Just want to leave this here since if it was unclear to one user it probably is to others

I think im doing a terrible job asking my question so I just want to reclarify

```
while True:
    z = 1
    j = 0
    r = z + j
    while r < 10:
        j += 1
        print(z, j , r )
```

r always remains one, putting this code in an infinite loop. However, i defined r = z + j and j is getting incremented. I don't understand why the compiler is not re calculating what r is when it checks the condition

Comment: Basically for most programming languages such arithmetic and assignment works like a plain dumb calculator: Take numbers, calculate result, store it somewhere and don't care about it until someone (or some code) explicitly asks for it or modifies it.

Comment: "I don't understand why the compiler is not re calculating what r is when it checks the condition" – because you did not tell it to do that. A program will only do exactly what you tell it to do, no more, no less. If you give the instruction `r = z + j` it will add `z` and `j` and put the result in `r`. But it will not modify the result of `r` any further, unless you give a further specific instruction to do so. The value of a variable will not be "automatically" modified or updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a bit to zero in on, but I think the problem you're asking about is this infinite loop:

```
    while total < dist:
        val += 1
```

Neither `total` nor `dist` are modified by the statement `val += 1`.  It is therefore safe to say that if you ever get inside that loop, you will not get out of it; you will never execute any line outside the loop that might change either `total` or `dist`.

Note that this line:

```
total = pow(2, val)
```

does not *alias* the name `total` to the *expression* `pow(2, val)`, as if you did (for example) the following in C:

```
#define total pow(2, val)
```

Instead, when you do an assignment (in Python or in almost any other language), the expression on the right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated, and its resulting *value* (at that exact moment) is bound to the left-hand side of the assignment.  Hence after you run:

```
total = pow(2, val)
```

`total` has the value of 2 to the power of whatever `val` was *at the time you did the assignment*.  If `val` was `0`, then `pow(2, val)` returned `1`, and `total` is now `1`.  `total` is not bound to the expression `pow(2, val)`, or even to the expression `pow(2, 0)`, it is bound to the number `1` and nothing more -- nothing in `total` links it to the expression that originally produced that `1`.  If you print `total`, you will get `1`, and only `1`, until you assign some other value to `total`.

If you wanted `total` to dynamically update inside your loop, the solution would be to make it a function, like this:

```
    total = lambda: pow(2, val)
    while total() < dist:
        val += 1
```

`total` is now bound to a function that has the body `pow(2, val)`, and to get a value from it, we call it with the `()` operator.  This causes the body of the function to be evaluated *right then*, producing a new result based on whatever value `val` currently has.

It would be simpler, though, to just update `total` whenever you update `val`:

```
    total = pow(2, val)
    while total < dist:
        val += 1
        total = pow(2, val)
```

or even:

```
    total = pow(2, val)
    while total < dist:
        val += 1
        total *= 2
```

Comment: right total is not modified, but total is defined to be comprised of 2 values outside of the loop, and those values are updated, so why doesn't this update reflect in the while condition check?  ( total < dist ) and i update one of the values that comprises total.

Comment: Oh that actually helps clear up the question!  Lemme update my answer a bit.

Comment: @jojo33 total is defined outside of the loop, so when the loop runs again, total is not updated, its value was set before the poit that the loop loops back to (the while statement)

Comment: I think OP's confusion is that they were expecting variable assignments in Python to behave like macro definitions in C (I can't think of any language where the assignment operator behaves like that, FWIW -- there's a reason C has a special `#define` syntax for it, and a regular old `=` operator that behaves almost exactly like Python's `=` operator).

Comment: hi samwise, im still digesting your explanation, but you are indeed very wise. thanks a lot haha

Comment: Okay I see, normally I do write things like   total = pow(2, val)
    while total < dist:
        val += 1
        total *= 2, 
but this is the first time I tried something in this way and got burned for it, Learned a lot from this, thank you very much answer accepted